# How do I redirect OldSite.com to NewSite.com/Sub/NewPage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdirectory, forwarding

I need to redirect several URLs to a new site that will have pages that replace the old sites. I don't care if the URL is masked or not. I just need the URL's to go to the new pages on the new combined site.
For example:

- Oldsite.com redirects to NewSite.com/Sub/NewPage
- Oldsite2.com redirects to NewSite.com/Sub/NewPage2
- Oldsite3.com redirects to NewSite.com/Sub/NewPage3
- and so on.

I've tried domain forwarding on the DNS level, but that isn't working (likely because of the subdirectories).

Problem is the New site was developed in Webflow and I don't have access to implement custom code for redirects.

My thought is to host a separate site to act as a hub that handles all the custom redirects to the New webflow site.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement redirection rules on the old sites. Because that is where the request comes in. You want to redirect _from there_ to the new target.

Comment: Are all old sites hosted on a single server or are they independent? What access do you have to the old sites?

Comment: Most of the old sites where built in the early 2000s by a 3rd party. We maintain them through a janky control panel, but cannot add any custom code. Some of the old sites we updated with Webflow. As a cost saving measure we want to get rid of all the old sites and host their content on one big combined site.

Comment: We're a small department, so we all wear too many hats. That's why we prefer to use services like Webflow, which hosts the (already built) big combined site. Webflow allows us to develop and update quickly so we can accomplish all our other responsibilities.

Comment: Then you want to get into control of the old domains, change their DNS resolution to point somewhere where you have control. That is where you then want to implement redirection rules to the new resource location. That can all be the same or different systems, that does not matter. But you need to implement redirection rules in the old domains.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario here isn't entirely clear on the types of redirections you're attempting to do.

If you're trying to redirect all paths from the old site to a specific destination page, like this...

`oldsite.com/*` ➜ `newsite.com/sub/newpage`

...many modern DNS providers support that.

If yours does not, you can switch your nameservers to Cloudflare DNS free edition, and you'll have the ability to define up to 3 page rules that support wildcard redirections like this.